# Fill under line curve

Tags: r, data-visualization

For the sample dataset below, I would like to just plot the y as a smooth line with fill under the line using R.

I am able to get smooth line but not the color filled curve. Could someone please help me here?

```
date, y
2015-03-11, 71.12
2015-03-10, 34.0
2015-03-09, 11.1
2015-03-08, 9.62
2015-03-07, 25.97
2015-03-06, 49.7
2015-03-05, 38.05
2015-03-04, 38.05
2015-03-03, 29.75
2015-03-02, 35.85
2015-03-01, 30.65
```

The code I used to plot the smooth line is as follows. I am unable to get fill the portion under the line with a color

```
y <- df$y
x <- 1:length(y)

plot(x, y, type='n')
smooth = smooth.spline(x, y, spar=0.5)
lines(smooth)
```

[image]

**EDIT**
Using the polygon function does not give what is expected. The shaded area should be below the line not above

```
with(smooth, polygon(x, y, col="gray"))
```

[image]

Comment: you want the `polygon` function.  software questions are generally considered off-topic here

Comment: Sorry for posting in wrong forum, maybe an admin can move it to right forum? 
Also I updated with polygon function but it does not give the right output. Please check the edit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Describe a polygon by listing its boundary vertices in order as you march around it.**

This polygon's boundary consists of the curve *plus two more vertices* at the bottom right and bottom left.  To help you see them, I have overplotted the vertices, varying their colors by position in the sequence.

[image: Figure]

Here is the `R` code that did it.  It used `predict` to obtain coordinates of the curve from the `spline` object, then adjoined the x- and y-coordinates of the two extra points using the concatenation operator `c`.  To make the filling go to the axis, the plot range was manually set.

```r
y <- c(71, 34, 11, 9.6, 26, 50, 38, 38, 30, 36, 31)
n <- length(y)
x <- 1:n
s = smooth.spline(x, y, spar=0.5)
xy <- predict(s, seq(min(x), max(x), by=1)) # Some vertices on the curve
m <- length(xy$x)                         
x.poly <- c(xy$x, xy$x[m], xy$x[1])         # Adjoin two x-coordinates
y.poly <- c(xy$y, 0, 0)                     # .. and the corresponding y-coordinates
plot(range(x), c(0, max(y)), type='n', xlab="X", ylab="Y")
polygon(x.poly, y.poly, col=gray(0.95), border=NA)          # Show the polygon fill only
lines(s)
points(x.poly, y.poly, pch=16, col=rainbow(length(x.poly))) # (Optional)
```

Comment: Nicely illustrated. The smooth-object already has the values at the data-x points. Could just pull the `x` and `y` elements from the `s`-object and do this: `polygon(c(s$x[1], s$x, tail(s$x,1)) , c(0, s$y, 0) , col=gray(0.95) )`

Comment: @Bonded Although the spline does have values, they are crude. Normally one will extract a whole lot of vertices along any smooth and use them. To see the difference, replace the `by` parameter in `seq` by a smaller value, such as 0.1 or even 0.01.