# R: Fill area under curve with Polygon()

Tags: r, polygon

Is there an universal way to fill the area under a curve with the polygon() function?

As far as I understand the answer in this post:
[Fill under line curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016673/fill-under-line-curve) I would assume that `polygon(c(min(x), x, max(x)), c(min(y), y, min(y))` will *always* work, because it starts on the bottom left, goes up to the curve, down to the button right and then back to the beginning.

But it does not always work. Sometimes, I still get a graph like in this question: [Why polygon in R works with a full curve but not with a half curve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391205/why-polygon-in-r-works-with-a-full-curve-but-not-with-a-half-curve) where R simply draws a line and fills in under and above it.

So what would be an iput (or an other function) that will always work?

Comment: What's wrong with the answer to that question? It looks like the answer is simply to be sure to sort your input data by `x` (i.e., replace `x` with `x[order(x)]` and `y` with `y[order(y)]`). Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example-aka-mcve-minimal-complete-and-ver) if this is not the case.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the answer. I just wanted to point out that i've read this answer and that I understood it in a way that brings me to my idea for a solution. It wasn't meant as a critic, but rather as an explanation. If I use `order()`, the data gets ordered with increasing values (what is not what I want on a y-axis). I am not able to make an reproducable example unfortunately, since I can not upload my dataset and could not reproduce it with random values...

Comment: sorry, I made a typo. `y[order(x)]`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need `na.rm = TRUE` for `min(y)`? Anyways, here is a function giving you the possibility to specify a horizontal border to which to fill:

```
fill_to_border <- function(f, from, to, y_border = 0, col = 1) {
  curve_points <- curve(f, from, to) 
  polygon_x <- c(min(curve_points$x), curve_points$x, max(curve_points$x))
  polygon_y <- c(y_border, curve_points$y, y_border)
  polygon_points <- list(x = polygon_x, y = polygon_y)
  polygon(polygon_points, col = col)
}

fill_to_border(dnorm, -4, 0)
```

[image]